# Unable to understand scoping of a variable in python

Tags: python

I have written this simple function to check whether a given string is a palindrome

```
from math import ceil
p=0
def pal(s):
    y=0
    p=0
    for x in range(int(ceil(len(s)/2))):
        if s[x]==s[-x-1]:
            y+=1
            print y
    if y==int(ceil(len(s)/2)):
        print "Palindrome"
    else:
        print "Not Palindrome"
```

This works fine. However, I want to change the variable found to 1, if I find a palindrome. And to 0 otherwise. And through some other function I want to check

```
if found==0:
   do_something
else:
   do_something
```

I am getting variable not defined error. How do I resolve this?

Comment: There is no varaible `found` defined. So how you want to compare it to 3?

Comment: If i define it, then where do i need to define? I tried assigning found to 0 inside the function. If a palindrome is found, it does change its value to 1
from math import ceil
def pal(s):
    y=0
    p=0
    for x in range(int(ceil(len(s)/2))):
        if s[x]==s[-x-1]:
            y+=1
            print y
    if y==int(ceil(len(s)/2)):
        p=1
        print p
    else:
        p=0
        print p
but its not permanent. If I print the value of p after compile, its always 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's define a function that returns 1 if its argument is a palindrome and 0 otherwise:

```
def palindrome(s):
    return int(s == s[::-1])
```

Now, we can assign the result of the palindrome function to the variable `found` and do something with it, such as print:

```
found = palindrome('abba')
if found == 1:
    print "Palindrome"
else:
    print "Not Palindrome"
```

#### Using a global variable

It is also possible to return information from a function using a global variable:

```
def palindrome(s):
    global found
    found = int(s == s[::-1])

palindrome('abccba')
if found == 1:
    print "Palindrome"
else:
    print "Not Palindrome"
```

When global variables are used, however, code is often more difficult to debug and maintain.  Consequently, most use of global variables is discouraged.  Google's style guide for python, to take an example, discusses this issue in more detail under the heading: ["Avoid global variables."](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Global_variables).

Comment: Cool! This works. :) but why can't I just change the value of the variable and refer it later?

Comment: @abhidoeslinux You can.  I added to the answer a section on the use of global variables.